# Netbeans 12.0 + Payara micro 5 + OpenJDK 11 does not deploy war file

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, payara-micro

I'm writing a Jakarta application using

- Netbeans 12.0
- Payara micro 5.2020.7
- OpenJDK 11

The problem: The IDE does not deploy the war file if the app use

```
<maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
```

[image: Netbeans does not deploy using 11 source and target]

But if the app use

```
<maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
<maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
```

The IDE deploy the WAR file successfully :v

[image: WAR deployed successfullly]

I think that the Payara Netbeans plugin have an error working with JDK11 because if I run `mvn payara-micro:start payara-micro:stop` at a simple terminal all is ok (the WAR file is deployed successfully).

[image: All is ok running from terminal]

Some idea that what happened?

Comment: [1] What is your default Java platform when running NetBeans? You can get that from the _Java_ details on the **Help > About** screen. [2] Note that if you run  Payara from NetBeans it will use that version of Java as well, so if NetBeans is running using Java 8 the Payara will also run using Java 8, which may not be what you want. [3] Post all your screen shots in text form instead. That is a standard requirement/expectation on SO. [4] I don't see any error message when deploying to Payara using Java 11. If there is one then post it in your question.

Comment: [1] This is my Netbeans about info:

`Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0
Updates: Updates available to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 11.0.11; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04
Runtime: OpenJDK Runtime Environment 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.18.04
System: Linux version 4.15.0-142-generic running on amd64; UTF-8; es_GT (nb)`

[2] Java 11 for all (Netbeans and Payara)
[3] It was to show both the pom.xml and the result in the console
[4] No errors, is an empty project

Answer (score 0):

An unexpected error. JAVA_HOME has been configured correctly, Netbeans Platforms too, but OS alternative for java has a wrong value configured. The solution:

[image: Config java alternative]